# Statistically significant difference between real and dummy models

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation

Suppose I'm building a machine learning model, like logistic regression, and I want to compare its performance with a *dummy* model, like taking the mean of the features in my training set.

Suppose also that I train my models multiple times in order to get robust statistics. I can then plot a histogram of the test errors: suppose the two histograms (real and *dummy* models) are very close to each other (the means are $0.\text{something}$ apart).

Is there a way to quantify how different the two models actually are? Is a Student's t-test appropriate? How can I say whether the real model is actually better than the *dummy* one?

Comment: Actually the $R^2$ score, by definition, tells how much of the variance of the data is explained by the model _with respect to just taking the average_ already.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a dumb model will be predicting the flat rate of observed Relative Frequency of class as the probability ( at least that's what I use in problems I face )

I also believe to measure how good a model is you must be using some evaluation metric - Accuracy, ROC AUC etc. Measuring these metrics on your defined test set actually denotes how different the model are in terms of predictive power. I don't think a hypothesis testing is needed here ( although you have a way to do that but that will involve certain assumptions ).